# Getting accordion plugin work within Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, accordion

My website uses AJAX to present content. When click in main menu, page1.html opens in content-div. On page1.html I want to present content using jQuery accordion menu. How can I get it working in file called with AJAX?

Accordion menu requires these files are currently presented in index.html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.cookie.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.6.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('.accordion-1').dcAccordion({
            eventType: 'click',
            autoClose: true,
            saveState: false,
            disableLink: false,
            showCount: false,
            speed: 'normal'
        });         
    });
</script>
```

I'm using Design Chemicals jquery vertical accordion menu. http://bit.ly/eIMnl1

Comment: Are you asking how to load sub pages in the accordian with AJAX or are you have trouble loading the accordian when you populate your page via AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are running this plugin code before you AJAX appends the new elements in content-div.  Just put the initialization code in the success callback in your AJAX request.

```
success: function() {
    $('.accordion-1').dcAccordion({
        eventType: 'click',
        autoClose: true,
        saveState: false,
        disableLink: false,
        showCount: false,
        speed: 'normal'
    });
}
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Was this the answer that you were looking for?